# Accept any password at login attempt

Tags: linux, security, unix, passwords

After unsuccessful research on the internet, I am coming here to ask if any of you knew of a software/library that can make a linux (or osx) system accept any password for a given user, but silently login into a fake account if the password entered is not the right one.

I am aware this sounds a bit hollywood-ish or weird, but I would be really grateful if someone can recommend me one.

Best regards,

-Thomas

Comment: Welcome to Super User; unfortunately product recommendations are out of scope and so are off-topic here. You could try [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/), but check out what is [on topic](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)- in particular, it would be worthwhile explaining *why* you want this honeypot and what you expect to achieve. Cheers!

Comment: My suggestion is that you delete this post and create a new one. Do NOT ask for product recommendations. Instead, ask how to accomplish what it is you are trying to do and provide any research and effort you have put in to trying to solve the issue.

Comment: This is linux, you want something weird like that you have to write the code your self.  There is a PAM password authentication module, if you download the source code you could change the code, recompile, and install it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing. Password validation doesn't work that way.